# Ruby: NameError at '/signup' uninitialized constant User

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

I'm new to Ruby and working on creating a form that creates a new user when submitted. I have created my database (rake: 12.0.0) and am able to edit it when using tux (so I am assuming that my model files are correct). I am using Sinatra to launch the website (which works), but when I submit the form, I am receiving this error: **NameError at  '/signup' uninitialized constant User**. Given that I am able to edit the database in tux, I'm assuming that my actions.rb file is not accessing the models files, but I'm not sure why.

ruby: 2.4.1

puma: 3.9.1

sinatra: 2.0.0

tux: 0.3.0

I've looked at other threads with similar topics, but still can't seem to figure out what the problem is. Any help would be great! Thanks

If you need any other information let me know!

This is my models/user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :phone_number

end
```

actions.rb

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'

set :public_folder, 'public'
post '/signup' do
  [...params -> this section works so I omitted it]

  # Instantiate and save a User
  @user = User.create({firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname, email: email})
end
```

gemfile

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem 'rake'
gem 'activesupport'

gem 'sinatra'
gem 'sinatra-contrib'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord'

# gem 'puma'
gem 'tux'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'shotgun'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to require the user.rb file. Try this in your actions.rb file:

```
require_relative 'user'
```

Comment: Thank you! I also had to establish a connection with Active Records in my user.rb but it works now. Thanks!